# jqplot bargraph not displaying data

Tags: javascript, jqplot

Not getting any errors from firebug.  Not showing in any browser.  Was working previously and stopped working about a week ago.  Sample of the code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Generic names for multiple graphs
    var First = $('#hfFirstOrder').val().split(",");
    var Second = $('#hfSecondOrder').val().split(",");
    var Third = $('#hfThirdOrder').val().split(",");
    var ticks = $('#hfDaysOrder').val().split(",");
    var maxValue = parseInt($('#hfMaxOrder').val());
    var FirstArray = [];
    var SecondArray = [];
    var ThirdArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < First.length; i++) {
        FirstArray.push(parseInt(First[i]));
        SecondArray.push(parseInt(Second[i]));
        ThirdArray.push(parseInt(Third[i]));
    }
    plotGraph("stackedPurchase", [FirstArray, SecondArray, ThirdArray], true, ticks, "Orders", maxValue, '#000', "Completed",
                '#00F', "Ship/Pick", '#F00', "Back Order");

        function plotGraph(chartName, total, stackBool, tick, yLabel, maxValue, SC1, SL1, SC2, SL2, SC3, SL3) {
        plot = $.jqplot(chartName, total, {
            stackSeries: stackBool,
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: { barMargin: 20, barWidth: 10 },
                showMarker: false,
                pointLabels: { show: false }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    label: "Days",
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: tick
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: yLabel,
                    padMin: 0,
                    tickInterval: parseInt(maxValue * .1),
                    min: 0,
                    max: maxValue,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '%d' }
                }
            },
            series: [{ color: SC1, label: SL1 },
            { color: SC2, label: SL2 },
            { color: SC3, label: SL3 }
        ],
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'outside'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then there's a call in the html for

```
<div id="stackedPurchase" style="height:450px;width:900px;" runat="server"></div>
```

And the various hidden values are csv strings from the code behind.  According to firebug they are being passed in correctly (right formats and correct number of each variable).  Judging from my coding experiences recently, its probably something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found the problem.  Apparently

```
parseInt(maxValue * .1)
```

gets pissy and returns 0 if maxValue is less than 10, and jqplot doesn't like 0 as a tick interval.  Found a better way to do intervals and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Got a partial answer, the first two graphs work now because someone else at work moved the folders that the jqplot stuff was in without informing me.  Changing the address in the scripts at top fixed the problem.

But for some reason the third one isn't working.

```
plotGraph("graphQuote", [FirstArray, SecondArray, ThirdArray], false, ticks, "Quotes", maxValue, '#F00', "Request RFQ", '#00F', "RFQ", '#0F0', "Customer Quote");
```

SecondArray is all zero values, FirstArray is mostly zero and ThirdArray has a value in most of its fields.  Ticks has correct dates.